# Does encoding matter for JSON?

Tags: java, javascript, json, encoding

Does JSON only support Unicode? It doesn't seem like encoding matters if this is the case. Won't all JSON then be unicode, and the Charset just a matter of storage?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

From [the RFC](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4627), "JSON text SHALL be encoded in Unicode."  Unicode is really a character set, not an encoding, though.  It also says the "default encoding is UTF-8."  The same section explains how to distinguish between UTF-32BE, UTF-16BE, UTF-32LE, UTF-16LE, and UTF-8 based on the pattern of nulls.

In summary, use UTF-8 unless you have a strong reason to do otherwise.  However, you can use a different Unicode encoding.

Comment: @Stephen, thanks for the correction.  I thought (incorrectly) that SHALL was equivalent to SHOULD.  You're right that it's actually equivalent to MUST.

Comment: @Stephen, yes, I was aware of that RFC.  But I didn't check it before answering. :)

Answer (score 0):

Encoding would matter when you read or parse the JSON string to be sent in the response. So response encoding would come into play
When reading a JSON data from request, you would need to make sure you have encoding set for that case as well.